# Remove white space from my aspx page using regex

Tags: asp.net

i need to remove few things from my aspx page.
1) need to remove white space from my aspx page.
2) need to remove all html & css comment from my aspx page.
3) need to remove javascript comment like single line & multi line comment

please give me the best code to do the above.

### i search google and found the code below

```
 protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        using (HtmlTextWriter htmlwriter = new HtmlTextWriter(new System.IO.StringWriter()))
        {
            base.Render(htmlwriter);
            string html = htmlwriter.InnerWriter.ToString();

            if ((ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("RemoveWhitespace") + string.Empty).Equals("true", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                // regex for removing white space
                html = Regex.Replace(html, @"(?<=[^])\t{2,}|(?<=[>])\s{2,3}(?=[<])|(?<=[>])\s{2,3}(?=[<])|(?=[\n])\s{2,3}", String.Empty);

                // regex for removing js comment
                //

                html = Regex.Replace(html, @"(?<=[^])\t{2,}|(?<=[>])\s{2,}(?=[<])|(?<=[>])\s{2,11}(?=[<])|(?=[\n])\s{2,}|(?=[\r])\s{2,}", String.Empty);
                // regex for removing white space again
                html = Regex.Replace(html, @"[\f\r\t\v]?([\n\xFE\xFF/{}[\];,<>*%&|^!~?:=])[\f\r\t\v]?", "$1");
                // regex for removing html comment
                html = Regex.Replace(html, @"((<!-- )((?!<!-- ).)*( -->))(\r\n)*", String.Empty);
                // regex for removing line break & carriage return
                html = Regex.Replace(html, @"((\/\*[\s\S]+?\*\/)|(\/\/.+))", String.Empty);
                html = html.Replace(";\r\n", ";");
            }
            writer.Write(html.Trim());
        }
    }

the above code remove white space js comment but affect my script tag which is like
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(!window.jQuery)
    {
         document.write("<script type='text\/javascript' src=<%= this.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js") %>><\/script>");
    }
</script>
```

so please show me regex which does not affect **</script>** this type of character in script.
another request that please give me one regex which will do like
1) need to remove white space from my aspx page.
2) need to remove all html & css comment from my aspx page.
3) need to remove javascript comment like single line & multi line comment

i am expecting optimize code from the forum guys. thanks

Comment: Why don't you just pre-compile your aspx page into a DLL?

Comment: The time and computer power you spend to run this function is huge compared to the few spaces that you remove. And if you gzip your page, you almost not gain anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I suggest to put aside the Regex, because you going to end with broken html/javascript and other code.

Also you take too much time to run this function on ever render just to gain some spaces out, that they compressed well with the gzip anyway.

I only suggest **to minimize the css and the javascript** using the Microsoft Ajax Minifier.

http://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/

There are and some other, but I have check this one with difficult libraries like jQuery and Yahoo YUI and creates, on the fly, final code no errors at all. I also suggest here to connect all your javascript files to one, and make minifier ones, then cache it and use the cache. I have read that this minifier is part of the asp.net 4.5 and come with new functions that make all that almost automatically.

This is a simple example to minifier javascript on fly. Please note, that first we merge all files and then send them all together to minifier. If you minifier every javascript file separate, you can not then merge them together because minifier remove the last not used ';' character and make some other parameters change so that you can not combine them after the minfication.

```
Minifier MyMin = new Minifier();
CodeSettings cs = new CodeSettings();
cs.MinifyCode = true;
cs.OutputMode = OutputMode.SingleLine;

FinalJavascript = MyMin.MinifyJavaScript(MyOriginalJavascript, cs);
```